# Newsletter queue not working in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, newsletter

I am trying to put a newsletter template in queue, but whenever I fix a time and save it , it gets saved for previous time by 4 hours. Even if I put a time that is somewhere in future, newsletters are not being sent. What could be the problem, and how to address it.

Answer (score 2):

1. Choose correct timezone in

> Stores-> Configuration -> General -> General -> Locale Options ->
>   Timezone

2. You have to set Cronjob to send newsletter automatically on scheduled time. or you can manually run

> php bin/magento cron:run

command to run cron manually.

For more details please visit below link:

[How to Setup Cron Job Magento 2 - Schedule Tasks](https://www.mageworx.com/wiki/cat/magento-2-email-newsletter/)

**Note**: I had to install SMTP extension (https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-smtp/) to send emails from my localhost.